# How to stop auto enter in css?

Tags: css, enter

I'm pretty noob in html and css since I just started. I'm trying to implement something in a creation but I don't know to delete the auto enters in the title.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);


html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #405166 0%, #656f6f 100%);
}

.container{
  margin: auto;
}


h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 47px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
}


.title{
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-5deg);
  display: block;
  margin-left:50%;


}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="container">
  <h1>
    <br />
    <span class="title" style="color:#e55643;">Burger</span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
  </h1>
</section>

</body>
```

I'd like to have burger and school next to each other without deleting the colors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV6i6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,... not sure this is what you wanted

```
<body>
  <section class="container">
  <h1>
    <br />
    <span class="title" >
       <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label>
       <label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
    </span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
  </h1>
</section>

</body>
```

////////to remove space between labels do this.

```
<body>
  <section class="container">
  <h1>
    <br />
    <span class="title" >
       <label style="color:#e55643;">Burger</label><label style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</label>
    </span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
  </h1>
</section>
```

remove the space between label it should be on same line without space

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked. Just one more question but now there's a little space between burger and school. Do you know how to fix this please?

Comment: i have edited my anwser check it out  and if it helps give thumbsup

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

`.title { display: block }` is causing the elements to break into new lines. Using `display: inline-block` will allow you to `rotate` the element while keeping them on the same line.

```
.title{
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Additional reading: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);


html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #405166 0%, #656f6f 100%);
}

.container{
  margin: auto;
}


h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 47px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: #533d4a 1px 1px, #533d4a 2px 2px, #533d4a 3px 3px, #533d4a 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
}


.title{
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="container">
  <h1>
    <br />
    <span class="title" style="color:#e55643;">Burger</span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</span>
    <span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
  </h1>
</section>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ! :)

Comment: Sure thing. Go ahead and "Accept" the answer if you're content

Answer (score 0):

```
  <h1>
<br />
  <span class="title" style="color:#e55643;">Burger</span><span class="title" style="color:#2b9f5e;">school</span><span class="title" style="color:#f1c83c;">afspraken</span>
```

you will have no gap between them now :)

just write the spans in the same line, not on different lines

let me know if this works

Comment: I checked it and it works! just write all the <span></span> on the same line.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/txi35pf5jyez15m/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-17%20at%2019.36.43.png?dl=0